# Comparing two tables with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am having a great deal of trouble with this problem. I am trying to compare two different tables from two different databases to see what tuples have been added, what tuples have been deleted, and what tuples have been updated. I do that with the following code:

```
from sqlalchemy import *

# query the databases to get all tuples from the relations
# save each relation to a list in order to be able to iterate over their tuples multiple times
# iterate through the lists, hash each tuple with k, v being primary key, tuple
# iterate through the "after" relation. for each tuple in the new relation, hash its key in the "before" relation. 
# If it's found and the tuple is different, consider that an update, else, do nothing.
# If it is not found, consider that an insert
# iterate through the "before" relation. for each tuple in the "before" relation, hash by the primary key
# if the tuple is found in the "after" relation, do nothing
# if not, consider that a delete.

 dev_engine = create_engine('mysql://...')
 prod_engine  = create_engine('mysql://...')

def transactions(exchange):
    dev_connect = dev_engine.connect()
    prod_connect = prod_engine.connect()

    get_dev_instrument = "select * from " + exchange + "_instrument;"
    instruments = dev_engine.execute(get_dev_instrument)
    instruments_list = [r for r in instruments]
    print 'made instruments_list'

    get_prod_instrument = "select * from " + exchange + "_instrument;"
    instruments_after = prod_engine.execute(get_prod_instrument)
    instruments_after_list = [r2 for r2 in instruments_after]
    print 'made instruments after_list'


    before_map = {}
    after_map = {}

    for row in instruments:
        before_map[row['instrument_id']] = row
    for y in instruments_after:
        after_map[y['instrument_id']] = y
    print 'formed maps'
    update_count = insert_count = delete_count = 0

    change_list = []
    for prod_row in instruments_after_list:
        result = list(prod_row)
        try:
            row = before_map[prod_row['instrument_id']]
            if not row == prod_row:
                update_count += 1
                for i in range(len(row)):
                    if not row[i] == prod_row[i]:
                        result[i] = str(row[i]) + '--->' + str(prod_row[i])
                result.append("updated")
                change_list.append(result)
        except KeyError:
            insert_count += 1
            result.append("inserted")
            change_list.append(result)

    for before_row in instruments_list:

        result = before_row
        try:
            after_row = after_map[before_row['instrument_id']]
        except KeyError:
            delete_count += 1
            result.append("deleted")
            change_list.append(result)

    for el in change_list:
        print el

    print "Insert: " + str(insert_count)
    print "Update: " + str(update_count)
    print "Delete: " + str(delete_count)

    dev_connect.close()
    prod_connect.close()

def main():

    transactions("...")

main()
```

`instruments` is the "before" table and `instruments_after` is the "after" table, so I want to see the changes that occurred to change `instruments` to `instruments_after`.

The above code works well, but fails when `instruments` or `instruments_after` is very large. I have a table that is over 4 million lines long and simply trying to load that into memory causes Python to exit. I have tried overcoming this issue by using `LIMIT, OFFSET` in my queries to append to the `instruments_list`s in pieces, but Python still exits because two lists of that size simply take up too much space. My last option is to choose a batch from one relation, and iterate through batches of the second relation and make comparisons, but that is extremely error prone. Is there another way to circumvent this problem? I have considered allocating more memory to my VM but I feel that the space complexity of my code is the issue and that is what should be fixed first.

Comment: This don't answer your question, but to make MySQL diffs http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/diff.html could be useful